# Initials separated by periods (e.g. J.E.F. Smith)

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database I have a column that holds the initials of a person. However not all input is nice and clean. To give an example the initials for the name John Edward Fredrick Smith should be J.E.F.

Unfortunately in our database you would also find JEF or J.EF or JE.F. or J E F.

I thought I'd use the replace function to first remove all spaces and periods and then add periods after each letter. That last part (the adding a period after each letter) is the hard part. I just can't figure out how to do that in MySQL.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Vincent

Comment: Thank you David, Matthew and Giovanni. I'm sure with these examples and wise words I'll come a long way.

Comment: @David: It's data that has been put in the database by customers. I don't have the authority to change that. I'll be using your suggestions to create a work around. It's nasty, but unfortunately the way it is, right now. I'll still keep lobbying for clean data because I agree with you that that is the way to go. ;-)

Comment: All three answers are great, but I can only pick one, it appears. Because I'm also interested in creating functions I'll pick that one. Thanks again, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Matthew has suggested, you can write a function that iterates over chars to sanitize initials. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION sanitize_initials(name VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 set i = 1;
 set temp:='';
 while i <= CHAR_LENGTH(name) do
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(name,i,1);
   if not ch in(' ','.') then
     set temp := CONCAT(temp,ch,'.');
    end if;
   set i:=i+1;
 END while;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can try:

```
select sanitize_initials('JEF'),
       sanitize_initials('JE.F'),
       sanitize_initials('J.E  F')\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
   sanitize_initials('JEF'): J.E.F.
  sanitize_initials('JE.F'): J.E.F.
sanitize_initials('J.E  F'): J.E.F.
```

It is possible to extends this technique to create a function that build initial from a name:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION initials_from_name(name VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 declare inword bool;
 set i = 1;
 set temp:='';
 set inword=false;
 while i <= CHAR_LENGTH(name) do
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(name,i,1);
   if ch in(' ','.') then
     set inword = false;  -- it is between of words
   else
     if inword is false then
       set temp := CONCAT(temp,ch,'.');
     end if;
     set inword = true; -- word is started
   end if;
   set i:=i+1;
 END while;
 set temp := substring(temp,1,CHAR_LENGTH(temp)-2);
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So if you try to compute initial for :

```
select initials_from_name('John Edward Fredrick Smith');

+--------------------------------------------------+
| initials_from_name('John Edward Fredrick Smith') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| J.E.F.                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use the previous function `initials_from_name` in a trigger to compute the initials. For me it is better to implements the this logic to the application side.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a function which looped over characters of the string to update any length string, but I'm guessing here you have a fairly limited range (i.e. you're unlikely to have records with more than four initials). If that's true you can do something like the following:

```
-- Setup example table
create table people (initials varchar(1024));

insert into people (initials)
values
  ('JEF'),
  ('J.EF'),
  ('JE.F.'),
  ('J E F'),
  ('J.E F  F');

-- Remove all spaces
update people
set initials = replace(initials, ' ', '');

-- Remove all periods
update people
set initials = replace(initials, '.', '');

-- Add periods after each letter
update people
set initials = 
  case 
    when length(initials) = 1 then initials
    when length(initials) = 2 then concat(substring(initials, 1, 1), '.', substring(initials, 2, 1))
    when length(initials) = 3 then concat(substring(initials, 1, 1), '.', substring(initials, 2, 1), '.', substring(initials, 3, 1))
    when length(initials) = 4 then concat(substring(initials, 1, 1), '.', substring(initials, 2, 1), '.', substring(initials, 3, 1), '.', substring(initials, 4, 1))
    else initials
  end;
```

SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fc7e/1

Edit: Note that I've used three separate update statements here to make it easier to understand, you could collapse this down to one or two statements if running this over a large table, to avoid multiple updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question directly first, then say why you probably don't want to do this & suggest an alternative...

**To Do What You've Asked For Directly**

Unfortunately IIRC mysql doesn't support user defined functions in the same was as SQL Server and so forth, which would make this cleaner, but you can do it be repeated used of text functions:

1. Strip the characters you don't want:
   `REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", "")`
2. Get each character and add periods, assuming that there could be up to four initials:
   `CASE WHEN LEN(initials)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(INITIALS,1,1) ELSE '' END CASE + CASE WHEN LEN(initials)>1 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(INITIALS,2,1) ELSE '' END CASE + CASE WHEN LEN(initials)>2 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(INITIALS,3,1) ELSE '' END CASE  + CASE WHEN LEN(initials)>3 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(INITIALS,4,1) ELSE '' END CASE`
   Of course you need to use the version of `initials` wrapped in replace here but I've skipped that for clarity.
3. Upper case the result:
   `UCASE(<all of the above>)`

This results in:

```
UCASE(
      CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""))>0 THEN     SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""),1,1) ELSE '' END CASE 
    + CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""))>1 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""),2,1) ELSE '' END CASE 
    + CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""))>2 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""),3,1) ELSE '' END CASE  
    + CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""))>3 THEN '.'+SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(initials, ".", ""), ".", ""),4,1) ELSE '' END CASE
    )`
```

Not exactly pretty, even when laid out in a more readable form...

**Why You Probably Don't Want To Do This**
<sub>(other than the collection of functions above being ugly and a faf to include where-ever it is needed and more faf to maintain in amongst seas of other SQL code)</sub>

- Using functions in search clauses like this means that any index covering the `initials` column would not be used which may result in a table scan instead of an index search if there are no other search clauses that can use indexes. Research what "sargable" means with respect to search/sort clauses and indexes (your starter for ten: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)
- It assumes that the only extra characters you are going to see are space and period. If you get errant data in with, for example, a comma instead, this won't quite work. Adding all other characters to those being `REPLACE()`ed is likely to be impractical.

**What I Would Do Instead**

*Clean the data.*
*And keep it clean.*
That way you can search and sort easily without worrying about nasty function sequences for string reformatting.

Use the above function mess to update any existing values in `initials` and update your business logic to correctly format the strings on the way in in future. Instead of updating your code elsewhere it might be easier to implement a trigger that fixes the data as it is inserted into that column, this way you only have to make one change even if your app interacts with that column in many places (though the usual warnings about triggers apply: document them well otherwise you have black-box behaviour that will confuse future maintainers (including potentially the future you!)) and be careful to verify their efficiency).

If mySQL supports check constraints then implement one of those to enforce that only letters (and periods if you want them, see below) are present.

With regard to the periods when cleaning the data: I personally wouldn't include them as I'd consider them to be display formatting only (to be applied elsewhere) and not part of the data. Others may of course disagree.